# How to set current Identity user as an attribute when filling out a form?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So far I have created a "Form" model class which has an entity IdentityUser User and other entities

```
public class Reports
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set;}
    public IdentityUser User{ get; set;}
}
```

To save this data to my entity framework DB I am using the following code but don't know how to pass the current user into the controller I can pass the user name or id but not the user themself.

```
@model Reports
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
<body>
    <div class="container1">

        @UserManager.GetUserId(User)
        <form asp-action="Submit" method="post" role="form">
 <div class=" form-group row">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="User" type="hidden" value="@UserManager.GetUserName()" />
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The user's ID or username *is* how you'd identify the user in your data.  What other information about the user are you looking to include and why?  Also, why do you want this information to come from the client?  Consider what would happen when someone modifies that value and now your server-side code thinks they're a different user.  The server-side code should already know who the user is when validating the request.  What's the overall goal here?

Comment: You don't need to pass the user, but the foreign key which is `User.Id` !!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need the full `IdentityUser`? To save something in DB usually you only need the user id.